# Button Debouncing in XMEGA AVR

Tags: c, avr

I'm trying to make a simple on/off switch in xmega. For example, if I press once, it should say

> good

and if I press it again, it should say

> bad

and so on..

I know how to do button debouncing in Arduino, but I really have no idea with AVR. Can someone possibly help me, or give me some example code to study?

Here's my code so far:

```
if (!(PORTH_IN&PIN0_bm)) 
{
    if (Mode1 != 1)
    {
        Mode1 = 1;
        printf("%d\n", Mode1);   
    }
}

if (!(PORTH_IN&PIN0_bm))
{
    if (Mode1 != 0)
    {
        Mode1 = 0;
        printf("%d\n", Mode1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about to build the debounce with some hardware like a 555 timer?. It is more reliable than doing it with software.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a small state machine for this:

```
static int debounce_guard;
static int button_has_been_pressed;

void read_button_state()
{   
    switch(button_is_pressed)
    {
        case YES:
            if(debounce_guard == 0)
            {
                button_has_been_pressed = 1;
            }
            break;
        case NO:
            if(button_has_been_pressed)
            {
                /* Do stuff here */
                debounce_guard = 10000;
                button_has_been_pressed = 0;
            }
            break;
    }

    if(debounce_guard > 0)
        debounce_guard--;
}
```

(button_is_pressed variable should reflect the state of the gpio pin)

The idea is that debounce_guard should make you ignore redundant bouncing for the button and this variable should be decreased either with some timer or just in the function itself like in the code shown. The state machine will react then the user releases the button.

Comment: can you be more spesific sir? i mean, is that read_button_state supposed to be written like that or what. i still blank right now. can you just give me an example with actual 'code'?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. This is actual 'code' and I do not think I can be more clearer than this. When the program is started you can call this function with an interval that works well with the overall speed of your system/cpu. Just remember to change the button_is_pressed variable to match the register for your specific hw where the button is connected. You wrote PORTH_IN&PIN0_bm in your example so I guess this is the correct register and mask for the button.

Comment: it wont work, i dunno why.. am i doin it wrong.. i posted the code bellow

Comment: I would love you help you more, but it is very hard from where I am sitting. You need to do some debugging to understand exactly what is happening. Do you call the function at a good interval ? Does PORTH_IN&PIN0_bm change values when you press the button ? etc.

Comment: the interval is good.. i think.
and that porth_in&pino_bm, yes.. that changes the value. i could make a simple button function with that, but not with this on/off thing im tryin to do.
i could send you my whole code if you want.. boy, im really hittin a road block like literally. ive been workin on this since last 2 weeks and nothin changes.

Comment: Does the debounce_guard decrease in value down to 0 ?

Comment: i, dont know..? how to do that?

Comment: i was just declare that as variable

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental question to debouncing buttons using software solution is to know CPU frequency. XMegas can operate at 32MHz and higher.
Solution proposed here by staringlizard:

```
debounce_guard = 10000;
...
if(debounce_guard > 0)
    debounce_guard--;
```

is not good if you later decide to run your application using higher CPU rate.
Let's say your XMega runs @ 32MHz, above loop will be executed in less than 1/3 of a millisecond. Not good, if a human presses a button.
Much better solution is the following:

```
void read_button_state(){
    ...do your logic here

    _delay_ms(500);//delay for 500 ms
}
```

In this case you will always have about 500 ms time to get rid of hardware bouncing problems.